# Multiple subscribe angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular6, rxjs6

i am building an e-shop with some products. The user can add to cart and he can see the products he has added. I have three categories. One category is all products where i display all products and one fruits and bread category where i display specific products..Everything is working fine but when i change category  without clicking the add to cart button angular performs the addToCart method..I think its a problem with multiple subscriptions and memory leak..How can i do this with better coding?Here is my ts and html angular files.

My products.ts

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CategoryService} from '../category.service';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/index';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import {ShoppingCartService} from '../services/shopping-cart.service';
import {Product} from '../models/product';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css'],

})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  products: any;
  filteredproducts: any;
  category: any;
  res: any;
  categoryid: any;
  cartId: any;
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();





  constructor(private service: CategoryService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private cartService: ShoppingCartService) {


  }


ngOnInit() {

  this.route.queryParamMap.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(params => {
    this.category = params.get('category');
    this.cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if (this.category) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.service.allProductNames(this.category, this.cartId).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(data => {
                this.filteredproducts = this.products = data;
            });
        }, 500);

    } else {
        if (this.cartId === null) {this.cartId = -1; }
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.service.getProducts(this.cartId).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(data => {
                this.filteredproducts = data;
            });
        }, 500);


    }

  });


}


    addToCart(products: Product) {

        const cartId = this.cartService.getOrCreateCartId();

        if (!cartId) {
         const imero = new Date().getTime();
         this.cartService.create(imero).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(res => {
           this.res = res;
           localStorage.setItem('cartId', this.res.id);
           this.route.queryParamMap.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(params => {
           this.categoryid = params.get('category');
           if (this.categoryid) {
            this.cartService.createItem(products.id, this.res.id).
            takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(res1 => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.service.allProductNames(this.category, this.res.id).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(data => {
                        this.filteredproducts = this.products = data;});
                }, 500);

            });

           } else {
           this.cartService.createItem(products.id, this.res.id).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(res2 => {
               setTimeout(() => {
                   this.service.getProducts(this.res.id).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(data => {
                       this.filteredproducts = data;
                   });
               }, 500);

           } );
              }

                });
            });

        }


        else {
            this.route.queryParamMap.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(params => {
                this.categoryid = params.get('category');
                this.cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
                if (this.category) {
                    this.cartService.createItem(products.id, this.cartId).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(res1 => {});
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.service.allProductNames(this.category, this.cartId).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(data => {
                            this.filteredproducts = data;
                            });

                    }, 500);

                } else {
                    this.cartService.createItem(products.id, this.cartId).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(res1 => {});
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.service.getProducts(this.cartId).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(data => {
                            this.filteredproducts = data;
                            console.log(this.products);});

                    }, 500);
                }





            });

        }
    }



ngOnDestroy() {
  this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
  this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
}

}
```

My products.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
<app-product-filter></app-product-filter>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
      <ng-container  *ngFor="let p of filteredproducts; let i = index">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <img  class="card-img-top" src="{{p?.imageUrl}}" style="max-height: 200px; width: 100%;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{p?.title}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{p?.price | currency: 'EUR': symbol }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <button (click)="addToCart(p)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add to Cart</button>
                    <div *ngIf="p?.quantity!=0">{{p?.quantity}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div *ngIf="(i+1) % 2 === 0" class="w-100"></div>
      </ng-container>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never subscribe in subscribe. You can change your code like this:

```
this.route.queryParamMap.mergeMap(params => {
    this.category = params.get('category');
    this.cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if (this.category) {
       return this.service.allProductNames(this.category, this.cartId);
    } else {
        if (this.cartId === null) {
           this.cartId = -1;
        }
        return this.service.getProducts(this.cartId);    
    }
  }).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(data => this.filteredproducts = data);
```

You should subscribe your queryParams only once and it should be in ngOnInit. These are the following point you should conside in your add to cart method:

1. You already declared category property use that in your method. Don't subscribe queryParams.
2. Use mergeMap rxjs operator to remove nested subscribe.
3. Nested subscription will not unsubscribe when component will destroy.
4. You should not use setTimeout in your subscribe. Use debounceTime rxjs operator

Comment: Thank you :) I am trying to fix the addToCart method but with the mergeMap, and the code inside is not working..My program doesn't go inside..i follow the same logic..Inside ngOnInit everything is okay but outside the mergeMap doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: i fixed it..Thank you so much for your help